# why the first Dynamic_cast did not cast to base class?

Tags: c++, dynamic, casting

I thought the first "pd" can cast to Base class.

I tried to change `Derived *pd;` to `Base *pd;` and `pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);` to `pd = dynamic_cast<Base*>(pba);`

However, these two also don't cast to Base class as well.

The output always shows

Null pointer on second type-cast.
Null pointer on third type-cast.
Null pointer on fourth type-cast.

How can i get first type-cast?

also why my code doesnt show the first type-casT?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>
 using namespace std;
 class Base { virtual void dummy() {} };
 class Derived : public Base { int a; };
 class DerivedSecond : public Base { int b; };
  int main() {
      try {
        Base * pba = new Derived;
        Base * pbc = new DerivedSecond;
        Base * pbb = new Base;

        Derived* pd;
        Base * pbase;

       pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);
       if (pd == 0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast.\n";


       pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pbc);
       if (pd == 0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast.\n";
       pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pbb);
       if (pd == 0) cout << "Null pointer on third type-cast.\n";
       pbase = dynamic_cast<Base*>(pba);
       if (pd == 0) cout << "Null pointer on fourth type-cast.\n";


}
catch (exception& e) { cout << "Exception: " << e.what(); }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0b47582affcb0a9

Comment: For fourth type-cast you check `(pd == 0)` but i think it should be `(pbase == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `dynamic_cast` here is `pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);` This does not cast to a `Base` class because the target of a cast is specified within the `<>` symbols, and here the target is a `Derived` pointer.

To cast to your `Base` class, you need to use `dynamic_cast<Base*>`.

Comment: When i changed the first `dynamic_cast pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);` to `dynamic_cast<Base*>` It dosen't show the output which is out << "Null pointer on first type-cast.\n";